# Ui-grid sorting, filtering template celll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a linq template cell in UI-grid. the code in Controller:

```
var Station = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a target="_blank" href="{{row.entity.station.href}}">{{row.entity.station.text}}</a></div>';
and
       columnDefs: [
      { name: 'Station', cellTemplate: Station },
```

How can I add sorting, filtering this column by Station.Text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing name property of the column to station.text the column could be sorted and filtered by text while showing a link as described in the template.